# MySQL Find records in one table that has no value of a column in another table

Tags: mysql

I have table1, containing columns (simplified):

```
+-------------------------+
| id | user_id | username |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |     123 | peter    |
|  2 |     234 | john     |
+-------------------------+
```

and table 2, containing columns (simplified):

```
+----------------------------------+
| id | user_id | checklist_item_id |
+----+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |     123 |               110 |
|  2 |     123 |               111 |
|  3 |     123 |               112 |
|  4 |     234 |               110 |
|  5 |     234 |               112 |
+----------------------------------+
```

As shown above, Each entry for user_id from table1, has multiple entries for that user_id with multiple checklist_item_ids.

I am interested in returning ONLY records that does NOT have an entry in the second table for checklist_item_id = 111. The query must return only:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|     234 |
+---------+
```

As user with user_id 123 DO have an entry in table two with checklist_item_id of 111.

Comment: use `not exists`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from  table1 t1 where t1.user_id not in
( select user_id from table2 t2
   where t2.user_id=t1.user_id
   and checklist_item_id=111
)
```

Or use `not exist` which is efficient than not in

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 where not exists
    ( select 1 from table2 t2  where t2.user_id=t1.user_id and 
    checklist_item_id=111
    )
```

[DEMO in Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1217b31a08b4663ffc1256314df31196)

```
id  userid  itemid
4   234     110
5   234     112
```

In case you need only one id then it would be

```
select distinct t1.userid from  t1 where not exists
    ( select 1 from t1 t2  where t2.userid=t1.userid and 
    itemid=111
    )
```

output

```
userid
  234
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b163ea1ba99a903a8c4d4f8dfc378316)

Comment: Thank you. I am only interested in the user_id, so I would group by user_id. Correct?

Comment: @KobusMyburgh https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b163ea1ba99a903a8c4d4f8dfc378316 check this which returns only userid

Comment: Sorry, yes, I saw after that there was a second demo. Thanks. Have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use subquery, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE user_id NOT IN
    (SELECT user_id
     FROM table2
     WHERE checklist_item_id = 111)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It also worked, but the comprehensiveness of the first answer got accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest and efficient approach would be using `LEFT JOIN`, and filtering out those rows, where there is no matched record for `checklist_item_id = 111`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND 
                          t2.checklist_item_id = 111 
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It also worked, but the comprehensiveness of the first answer got accepted.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh no worries about the accepted answer. But for your practical purposes, you should avoid subqueries if you can use a Join based solution. It will be significantly more efficient